# Viewcontroller with UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How to go to a certain index tab bar view from a view controller with a custom UITabBar and without a tab bar controller.
So, when I press the custom UITabBar, I can straight go to that tab bar view with tab bar controller.
Like example, viewcontroller have a uitabbar. So I click "Favourite" will go to "Item 1" with a tab bar below.

[image: pic 1]

Comment: why are u not using a `UITabBarController`?

Comment: @dirtydanee u means the right hand side view controller change to UITabBarController?

Comment: how are u getting to this viewController? Is it opened from the UITabBarController? Is it presented modally?

Comment: I getting to this viewcontroller from side bar by using SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController